# Cooldown timer doubles in speed every time my startup countdown is executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player dies, one heart is removed from the health bar. A cool down timer starts that will refill the heart after 5 minutes. If the player should die again, the second heart will be removed but the timer will first finish its current cool down before restarting.

When the player dies the second time, the scene reloads and a countdown is shown to give the player time to get ready for the next try.

The problem is as soon as the countdown is finished and the timescale is set to 1, the cool down timer speed increases. If he dies again the timer speed increases again, till the first cool down timer completes and then resets and start the next cool down, then the speed is back to normal or if I exit the game and re-enter the timer is back to normal.

When the scene loads the timescale is 0. The countdown animation runs using a Mycoroutine script. After the animation is finished the timescale is set back to 1.

The cool down timer takes into account the time that a player is offline using a TimerMaster script and works 100%. Tested it on android and if the game moves to the background the timer works fine, using Time.unscaledDeltaTime instead of Time.DeltaTime.

The only problem I can't figure out is the speed increase every time the level restarts.

```
//this is used to call the countdown
public bool setCoundown = false;

void Start()
{
    countDown.SetActive(true);  //when active it sets setCountdown to true
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    if (setCoundown)
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountDown()); //set the timer to wait till the countdown is done
    }
}

IEnumerator CountDown()
{
    while (setCoundown == true)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(Mycoroutine.WaitforRealSeconds(0.5f));
        setCoundown = false;
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        RunGame();
    }
}

//This script is called by CountDown()
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public  static class Mycoroutine
{
    public static IEnumerator WaitforRealSeconds(float time)
    {
        float start = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

        while(Time.realtimeSinceStartup < (start + time))
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }    
}

//This is the cool down timer

using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerText : MonoBehaviour
public static TimerText instance;

[SerializeField]
private Text timeText;

private int health;
private float timer, minutes, seconds;

void Start()
{

    //get saved time that was needed to fill all health
    timer = GameController.instance.GetTimerTime();

    //deduct the offline time from the needed time
    timer = timer - TimerMaster.instance.CheckDate();

    //call the function to calculate offline time and set lives and timer value accordingly if the health is full then the timer value will be 300
    DateTimer();                                                                
}

void Update()                                                                   
{           
    health = GameController.instance.GetHealth();

    if (health < 3 && timeText.text == "0:00")
    {
        StartCoundownTimer();
    }
}

void StartCoundownTimer()                                                       
{
    if (timeText != null)
    {
        timeText.text = "0:00";
        InvokeRepeating("UpdateTimer", 0.0f, 0.01667f);
    }
}

void UpdateTimer()
{
    if (timeText != null)
    {
        timer -= Math.Max(Time.unscaledDeltaTime, 0);
        timeText.text = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", (int)(timer / 60), (int)(timer % 60));


        if (timeText.text == "0:00")
        {
            CancelInvoke();
            health = GameController.instance.GetHealth() + 1;
            GameController.instance.SetHealth(health);
            timer = 300;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say but this is way too messy. You don't even use the coroutine class you provided, which does nothing by the way. Most of the comments are redundant and just reduce readability of the code.

Comment: The problem most certainly is that you're calling the `InvokeRepeating` more than once in the new scene. You should be calling it on `Start()` as a safety measure.

Comment: A few notes... (1) Instead of comparing numeric values by converting them to strings and comparing the number directly. `number.ToString("00") == "00"` can simply be replaced with `number == 0`. (2) After assigning `seconds = (timer % 60)` you then test `if (seconds.ToString("00") == "60")`. Do you think this could ever be true? (3) Instead of the complicated `if (minutes.ToString("00") == "00" && seconds.ToString("00") == "00")` you could just say `if (timer == 0)`.

Comment: (4) For the time formatting you could just do `timeText.text = string.Format( "{0}:{1:00}", (int)(timer / 60), (int)(timer % 60) );`. Combine this with the tips above, and now you don't need the separate `minutes` and `seconds` variables at all! (5) If you did need variables like `minutes` and `seconds` (which you don't need here), they are only used in one function and should be local to that function, not class members.

Comment: @Michael I did the edits like you suggested. The display works fine, but the if (timer == 0) is never true. I edited the post. The timer just carries on counting into the negatives eg. 0:-59 and does not stop,

Comment: @Lyrca I have edited the post and hope its more readable. I did not include that this is a singleton and runs as soon as the game start and persists through all scenes. I can see how I can put it in start if it was just in the one scene, but the counter needs to show in all scenes. I will remove the singleton and let it start in every scene. I will reply with the findings. Thanks

Comment: My bad, I'll bet `timer` is going negative. If you log its value after each time you do the `-=` on it, it will probably show a negative value at the end. Easy to fix, you could change `timer -= Time.unscaledDeltaTime;` to `timer = Math.Max( Time.unscaledDeltaTime, 0 );`

Comment: @Michael I tried timer = Math.Max( Time.unscaledDeltaTime, 0 );  but now the timer never updates it stays at 00:00

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in my comment, sorry. Compare it with your original code (which successfully decremented the timer but let it go negative) and see if you can find my mistake.

Comment: @Lyrca I got it fixed by removing it as a singleton and attaching it to the text object in each scene, I still had to keep the call in update otherwise it would would not start the cool down when the player dies and only when the scene reloads. I also had to create an 'OnDestroy()' to save some values instead of saving them in 'OnApplicationQuit()', Thanks.

Comment: @Michael I edited the code in the post. I the only way I could get it to count down again was by adding the `timer -=` but then I still got the same result of `(timer == 0)` will still never be true, so I changed it to  `(timeText.text == "0:00")`. Now it is working and is still better than the code I had, If its still not what you wanted, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Let's go back to my tip #1: don't use string comparisons like this. Even if it seems to fix the problem, there will always be a better way to do numeric operations by just using numbers directly, not converting them to strings. The code you are looking for is `timer = Math.Max( timer - Time.unscaledDeltaTime, 0 );`. (There are a couple of other ways you could do this, but that is probably the simplest.) Study that carefully and see if it makes sense to you. If it is unclear what it does and why it works, drop a note and I will be happy to explain in more detail.